# Running multiple Tasks concurrently on Application_Start

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library

Can some friendly soul point me into the right direction.

Basically what i want to achieve is do some work during web application start. Mostly warm Up activities and setup tasks.

Those task are independent one of each other and they do not share any state so I thought that running them concurrently might be a good idea.

The solution I've came so far is the following:

```
    public void Execute()
    {
        IEnumerable<IStartupTask> startupTasks = PrepareStartupTasks();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(httpContext =>
        {
            HttpContext.Current = httpContext as HttpContext;

            Parallel.ForEach(startupTasks, startupTask => startupTask.Execute());                

        }, HttpContext.Current);            
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to run this independent work on Thread pool threads as fast as possible and finish the warm Up.

This is app start so i don't have the necessity to run them asynchronously although some of those tasks do some I/O (mostly API calls).

Is this a good approach to spin off some work during the bootstrap? Is seems to work but I may miss some potential pitfalls that's why I'm here :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good approach to spin off some work during the bootstrap?

Yes, but those tasks should not depend on `HttpContext.Current` because this is not available in the `Applicastion_Start` event and it is by chance that sometimes your code works. So once you get rid of this `HttpContext` from your `Application_Start` you will be fine. You should never write code that depends on HttpContext in a background thread. This is never guaranteed to exist. Here's an example how this could break. An HTTP request comes in and you start a background task capturing the current context. The background task takes let's say 10 seconds. The HTTP request has finished executing after 5 seconds and returned a response to the user. Consequently it is disposed. At the 10th second you attempt to use this captured (and by that time disposed) HttpContext in your background task. The result is a nice little exception.

Also I hope you are aware that all background tasks that you might have started in an ASP.NET application could be torn into pieces if the AppDomain is restarted by IIS (which basically can happen under circumstances which are not under your control). So if you need durability of those tasks you should definitely consider offloading them from your ASP.NET application into a separate service - for example that could be a Windows Service or just a plain Console Application that is scheduled to run at specified intervals by the Windows Scheduler.

Comment: And If you do not like to write your own windows service, use one of the existing libraries which does this. Take look at this post http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I am aware that AppDomain can shut down but it is not a problem because those are not some critical, durable operations. In this case it is fine to run them again as soon as AppDomain restarts.

My only problem is that one of those tasks internally uses HttpContext and to do some stuff and I was wondering how to deal with it.

Comment: If it is a background task it should not, by definition, depend or be bound to any HTTP context. If it does then I am afraid that you might be doing something very wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not in my ownership and decompiling I've noticed that it uses context internally. I may rethink of nature of that operation and move it out of background tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case all I can do is to wish you good luck. Just make sure to put some error logging into your background tasks so that you know how to manually recover the failed tasks from disposed HTTP contexts. Also catching the unhandled exceptions that you will get in your background threads could be a good idea to avoid bringing your AppDomain down everytime you get unlucky and hit a disposed HTTP context. I am afraid that there's no magic solution to this problem.

Comment: So to recap... I will remove the Tasks and use Context internally. I will get rid of the context and start a parent task that will wrap the Parallel.ForEach loop. Then Ill just fire it in AppStart. And for the future....no background Tasks that depend on HttpContext :) Are there any more considerations using this approach (calling an Http API for example in the Parallel loop in one of the Tasks would be reasonable?) Thanks again for the valuable input

Comment: I don't seen any issues with calling a remote HTTP API in a background task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99319/discussion-between-aleksander-bethke-and-darin-dimitrov).